# How can I create a new Django instance using reverse-foreign key without saving it to DB?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Suppose I have the following 2 Django models:

```
class MyModelA(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()

class MyModelB(models.Model):
    my_int = models.IntegerField()
    my_a = models.ForeignKey(MyModelA, related_name="MyModelB_a")
```

I can create instances of `MyModelA` in two ways:

```
# First technique:
>>> a = MyModelA.objects.create(my_int=5)

# Second technique:
>>> a = MyModelA(my_int=5)
>>> a.save()
```

If I know that I won't need to change `a` between instantiation and saving, I go with the first technique (to reduce lines of code). If I know that `a` will be changing between instantiation and saving, I usually go with the second technique shown above (to minimize database accesses).

Analogously when I want to create an instance of `MyModelB` from a method within `MyModelA` through the reverse-foreign-key relationship, I do the following:

```
# First technique:
>>> b = self.MyModelB_a.create(my_int=6)
```

But I don't know how to create instances of `MyModelB` through the reverse-foreign-key relationship using the second technique. How to do it? What function to call? I want to create an instance using the related_name `MyModelB_a` without saving it to the DB until I explicitly call `save()`

```
# Second technique:
>>> b = a.MyModelB_a.WHAT-GOES-HERE(my_int=6)
>>> b.save()
```

Comment: `a = MyModelA(my_int=5)` then `a.save()` then `b = MyModelB(my_int=6, my_a=a)`

Comment: That doesn't use of the reverse-foreign-key `MyModelB_a `

Comment: alright: `a = MyModelA(my_int=5)` then `a.save()` then `b = a.MyModelB_a.create(my_int=6)`

Comment: `create()` saves it to the database. I want to make a new instance using the related_name `MyModelB_a` without saving it to the DB until I explicitly call `save()`

Comment: True. It doesn't use reverse-foreign-key, but it creates the relationship just the same. You could also use `b=MyModelB(my_int=6)` then `a.MyModelB_a.add(b)`. One extra line of code isn't that bad.

Comment: I think you can't since the relationship is expressed via the value of the foreign key, which is the pk given to the obj when saved to the DB table

Comment: @mohan3d `myModelB_set` has been overridden by specifying a `related_name` in the foreign key. That is why I did not use it. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: I noticed then deleted my comment.

Comment: I think @halfnibble's sequence may be what you are looking for. If the relationship can be omitted when creating b, then link it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you mean .. you want something like `a.MyModelB_a.new(my_int=6)`. Something like `.build` in rails for example! I'm afraid that's not exist in django.

But if you just don't want to import `MyModelB` for some reason, you can use a work around if you are OK with that.

You can use `a.MyModelB_a.model(my_int=6, my_a=a)`

Edit:

Or you can override Manager class to implement your own method. I didn't try to override `RelatedManager` before, but it appears that it's [allowed in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#managers-for-related-objects) by `use_for_related_fields`.